# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I was trying to build a spring-mvc project without web.xml
On starting the app on the server it threw the following exception on sessionFactory.

My `AppConfig.class` is as follows which is used to initialize the persistence unit:

```
package com.myapp;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.myapp")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    builder
        .scanPackages("com.myapp.model")
        .addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return prop;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {

    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventtracker");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("root");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new     InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

And it is throwing exception :

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your last exception.

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
```

It means class file `javax/transaction/SystemException` is not on the classpath, thus jvm complain `NoClassDefFoundError`

Put all of your hibernate related jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of Hibernate 5.0.6 release for Hibernate 5.0.3 everything works fine. To fix a problem add this to pom.xml (if you use Maven)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

for Gradle build

```
compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'transaction-api', version: '1.1'
```

manual download

http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/transaction/transaction-api/1.1/transaction-api-1.1.jar